# what is the faster and best way to make a few million SOAP requests and save the results into SqlDb

Tags: model-view-controller, soap, async-await, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a million records in my table. I want to call a soap service and i need to do process in all the records in less than one hour. and besides i should update my table , insert the requests and responses in my other tables. but the code below works on less than 10 records every time i run my app.

I know My code is wrong,, I want to know what is the best way to do it.

```
 static async Task Send( )
    {
        var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

        using (AppDbContext entities = new AppDbContext())
        {
            var List = entities.Request.Where(x => x.State == RequestState.InitialState).ToList();

            Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, List.Count), async index =>
            {
                var selected = List.FirstOrDefault();
                 List.Remove( selected );
                var res1 = await DoAsyncJob1(selected);  ///await
               // var res = CallService(selected);
                var res2 = await DoAsyncJob2(selected);  ///await
                var res3 = await DoAsyncJob3(selected); ///await

               // var responses = await Task.WhenAll(DoAsyncJob1, DoAsyncJob2, DoAsyncJob3);

                // results.TryAdd(index.ToString(), res);
            }); 

        }

    }

    static async Task<int> DoAsyncJob1(Request item)
    { 
        using (AppDbContext entities = new AppDbContext())
        {
            var bReq = new BankRequest();
            bReq.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Amount);
            bReq.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now; 
            bReq.DIBAN = item.DIBAN;
            bReq.SIBAN = item.SIBAN; 
            entities.BankRequest.Add(bReq);
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
        return item.Id;
    }


static async Task<int> DoAsyncJob2(Request item)
    { 
        using (AppDbContext entities = new AppDbContext())
        {

        }
        return item.Id;
    }


static async Task<int> DoAsyncJob3(Request item)
    { 
        using (AppDbContext entities = new AppDbContext())
        {

        }
        return item.Id;
    }
```

Maybe the below lines are wrong :

```
  var selected = List.FirstOrDefault();
  List.Remove( selected );
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It is harder to see but `async index =>` is an `async void`. You lose all control over order of execution, completion and exceptions here.

Comment: The line that's wrong is `async index`. Parallel.ForEach is meant for *data parallelism*, not asynchronous operations. `async index` is essentially an `async void`. That's a fire-and-forget method that nodoby awaits or notices when it faults.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place?  It looks like all you need is a single call to SqlBulkCopy to quickly insert data into a database. Even without SqlBulkCopy, trying to add entities one by one using separate contexts and calls to SaveChanges is the slowest way possible, resulting in the maximum amount of blocking, especially if it's performed concurrently. At the very least add a large number of entities at once and let the ORM send all the changes as a single batch. That's still slower than SqlBulkCopy though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos   i want to  1) fetch one million records from my table ,,2)mark them as read in database ,, 3) call the soap service and send my list items one by one( cause i can't the list,,, the web service do not support) 4)save my sent request in my database 5) save the service response in my database

Comment: @sam why "mark them as read"? You're trying to treat the database as if it were a queue. The actual job is that you need to make a few million SOAP requests and save the results? I understand `save the service response in my database` but what does `save my sent request in my database` mean? In any case, why not use *SSIS* for this?

Comment: @sam with the TPL dataflow you could read all records using a SqlDataReader on one end and post them one by one to a `TransformBlock<>` that performs the SOAP request. You can configure the block to perform N operations in parallel. You can also set a boundary to its input buffer so it doesnt' end up buffering all 1-10M rows. The block can return the responses. Those responses can be sent to the *next* block and written to the database. To avoid entering rows 1 by1 you could use a batch block to batch responses into buffers of 10, 100, 1000 items, whatever is appropriate

Comment: How fast is that SOAP service and how many concurrent calls can it handle? Some services crash if you try to make even 10 concurrent calls. Or they may *charge* by the number of concurrent calls they support. If a response takes eg 10 seconds, it may not make sense to wait for enough responses to be gathered before writing them to the database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos   1)  mark it as read because i do not want to send a request twice 2) save request in to a table  cause i have some additional fields that are not saved in my request table  and it's some kind of hard code,, and it may change someday,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is a bad practice to use `async-await` within `Parallel.For` - you introduce only more load to the task scheduler and more overhead.

Second, you are right:

```
var selected = List.FirstOrDefault();
List.Remove( selected );
```

is very, very wrong.  Your code will behave in a totally unpredictable way, due to the race conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. what is your suggestion? How can i send my list items to the methods?

Comment: @sam I suggest you remove *all* of this code and use SqlBulkCopy to insert data as quickly as possible to the database. ORMs aren't meant for bulk operations. They simply *don't* use any of the bulk loading mechanisms offered by databases

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you. yeah i know bulkcopy is very fast,, but the point is that i want to call soap service for every 1 million record and get  response for every record and save responses into database.

Comment: @Sam that means *batching* and a processing pipeline, the same way an SSIS dataflow works. That's not data parallelism. That's what the TPL Dataflow library does. You should explain what you actually want to do in the question itself